# The confusion of back reasoning

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

We can conclude the proposition as ∀x∀y(((x>0 and y>0) and (x≠y)) ⇒(x + y)/2 > √xy) which x,y is in the real number domain

The book showed the solution below. isn't it assuming the conclusion is true.However assuming the conclusion((x + y)/2 > √xy) is true in the proposition is not allowed.

> **Question:**  Given two positive real numbers x and y, their arithmetic mean is **(x + y)/2** and their geometric mean is **√xy**. When we compare the arithmetic and geometric means of pairs of distinct positive real numbers, we find that the arithmetic mean is always greater than the geometric mean. [For example, when x = 4 and y = 6, we have 5 = (4 + 6)/2 > √4 · 6 =√24.] Can we prove that this inequality is always true?
>
> **Solution:** To prove that **(x + y)/2 > √xy when x and y are distinct positive real numbers**, we can work backward. We construct a sequence
> of equivalent inequalities. The equivalent inequalities are
>
> **(x + y)/2 > √xy,**
>
> **(x + y)<sup>2</sup>/4 > xy,**
>
> **(x + y)<sup>2</sup> > 4xy,**
>
> **x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> > 4xy,**
>
> **x<sup>2</sup> − 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> > 0,**
>
> **(x − y)<sup>2</sup> > 0.**
>
> Because **(x − y)<sup>2</sup> > 0 when x != y**, it follows that the
> final inequality is true. Because all these inequalities are
> equivalent, it follows that **(x + y)/2 > √xy when x != y**. Once we have
> carried out this backward reasoning, we can easily reverse the steps
> to construct a proof using forward reasoning. We now give this proof.
>
> Suppose that x and y are distinct positive real numbers. Then **(x − y)<sup>2</sup> > 0** because the square of a nonzero real number is positive. Because **(x − y)<sup>2</sup> =  x<sup>2</sup> - 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> > 0**. Adding 4xy to both sides, we obtain **x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> > 4xy**. Because **x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> = (x + y)<sup>2</sup>**, this means that **(x + y)<sup>2</sup> ≥ 4xy**.
>
> Dividing both sides of this equation by 4, we see that **(x + y)<sup>2</sup>/4 > xy**. Finally, taking square roots of both sides (which preserves the inequality because both sides are positive) yields **(x + y)/2 > √xy**. We conclude that if x and y are distinct positive real numbers, then their arithmetic mean **(x + y)/2 is greater than their geometric mean √xy**.

Comment: Not clear... If we show that a statement $P$ is equivalent to TRUE, with "equivalence preserving" transformation, we can conclude that $P$ is true.

Comment: What is the step in the above argument that you consider illegal ?

Comment: No, the book just says that the statement $$\forall x,y>0, x\neq y: \frac{x+y}2>\sqrt{xy}$$ is *equivalent* to the statement $$\forall x,y>0, x\neq y: (x-y)^2>0.$$ Since the last statement is true, we thus also know that the first statement is true

Comment: what is : sign meaning ,thx@MaximilianJanisch

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA because  ∀x∀y(((x>0 and y>0) and (x≠y)) ⇒(x + y)/2 > √xy)  is our proposition,that means ((x>0 and y>0) and (x≠y)) is the premises and (x + y)/2 > √xy is our conclusion,but the solution use conclusion to  work directly so it assumed the conclusion is true which it is not allowed

Comment: @MolyHoly Instead of parentheses I am using colons for my propositional statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backward reasoning chain from $(x+y)/2>\sqrt{xy}$ to $(x-y)^2>0$ is only included to show you *why* the formal proof starts from $(x-y)^2>0$.

The formal proof starts at the paragraph "Suppose $x$ and $y$ are distinct positive real numbers ..." and constructs a chain of reasoning that ends with $(x+y)/2>\sqrt{xy}$. But without the preceding explanation, the introduction of $(x-y)^2>0$ in the formal proof would be unmotivated and would seem somewhat arbitrary. You are being shown the scaffolding that was used to come up with the proof, rather than just the bare proof on its own.